# How to open a Java project in Eclipse design view?

Tags: eclipse

How do you open a project in design view in Eclipse? If I have an existing project in Java that has windows and Frames it is easy to use Open With... but I want to start a new form with design view. I know that this is possible in Eclipse because I am 90 percent certain that I have seen this done before.

I have right clicked and looked under New (where all of the class and other material can be opened, such as a new class, new project,...).

Comment: You may be thinking about [WindowBuilder](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/)

Comment: does this have to be installed or does it come automatically with Eclipse download?

Comment: I believe it depends on the exact download, some have it installed others don't.

Comment: Does it just show up in the area where you can select class, package, or those options under new?

Comment: I don't use it, have a look at [Quick Start](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wb.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Findex.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a Java form in design view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504813/how-to-open-a-java-form-in-design-view)

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late but it's under the text editor of the class that you created with WindowBuilder.
[image: picture]