# How to use JFrame properly?

Tags: java, jframe, window

So I started working on a project, and after some research of JFrame, I tried this to get my window for the project:

```
ImageIcon hello = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\JP\\Desktop\\hello.jpeg");

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
frame.setSize(640,480);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
frame.setIconImage(hello.getImage());
```

The frame comes up in it's correct size, but does not display the icon or have the correct background color.

Comment: The `setIconImage` sets the image for the title bar or when the window is minimized.  If you want the image to show on the frame add it to a `JLabel` and add the `JLabel` to the `JFrame`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting background color for the JFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081486/setting-background-color-for-the-jframe)

Comment: You would set the background of the JFrame's contentPane and not the JFrame itself. `frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to change the background of your frame, you should take a look at this [Setting background color of JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081486/setting-background-color-for-a-jframe), but either way I recommend you use the design tab of window builder, because that can make your life much easier, and such stuff can be manipulated easily. ([How to open a Java form in design view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504813/how-to-open-a-java-form-in-design-view/23505159))